# Cannot find CurvedChildLayoutManager in Android Wear com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0

Tags: android, wear-os

I want to create a Curved Layout in Android Wear. This is the [tutorial](https://developer.android.google.cn/training/wearables/ui/lists.html#creating).

In this web, Google let me create a class `MyLauncherChildLayoutManager extends CurvedChildLayoutManager`, but I can't find the `CurvedChildLayoutManager` in my Android studio.

I find the API with `android.support.wearable.view`, and this `CurvedChildLayoutManager` class is included in list.
This is the Api web: [CurvedChildLayoutManager](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/support/wearable/view/CurvedChildLayoutManager.html)

This is my module gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
  //this provided is auto create when I create my android wear project, I try to annotation it,but also can't find
  provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:+'
}
```

But in my Android studio External Libraries directory -> wearable-2.0.0, I can't find `CurvedChildLayoutManager` class.

Why can't I find? This wearable library version is the latest version.
Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the SDK manager, make sure you have the latest versions of the Android Support Library and the Android Support Repository. Then use version 2.0.2: (com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.2) and it should be there :)